# what's wrong here ? learning java

Tags: java

```java
package com.company;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        String result = currency.format(number: 1234837.343);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `number: 1234837.343` mean? That's not valid Java.

Comment: What error do you get? What don't you understand?

Comment: Did you perhaps try to write this code based on some picture/video? If yes then probably what you saw was editor which had enabled hints about names of method parameters which ware being set. Those names are not *part of the code* but part of how editor presents it (to make it more readable). So remove `number:` since it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 5):

You may have been misled about what to type by a screenshot of an IDE or something. You should not write `number: 1234837.343` as the parameter. Just write `1234837.343`. The `number:`  part is the parameter name that some IDEs show you, but it shouldn't be part of the actual code.